# Creating offline accessible map with hundreds of thousands of features

Tags: qgis

I have a few layers with a total of over 500.000 points (representing trees). I would like to create a map that;

- Should be accessible to people without any GIS programs
- Which can be accessed offline

I currently have a layered PDF, which serves its purpose but is not ideal. I tried to do it using the Qgis plugin `qgis2web`, but that doesn't seem to like having hundreds of thousands of points.

Does anyone know another or better way to achieve this?

(I can work with QGIS as well as ArcGIS Pro)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I think creating a GeoPDF is already a good way. Another solution would be the creation of a KML - but than again the user would need at least Google Earth. A good tutorial on how to create a layerd GeoPDF in QGIS: https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360003823717-QGIS-Creating-a-GeoPDF

Comment: If you are looking at both QGIS and ArcGIS Pro then I think you should ask separate questions for each do you can describe where you got stuck in your testing/research with each.